# How to add opacity to touchable opacity with image background in a flatlist?

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist that renders a clickable item (with touchable opacity) and an image background with some text in the middle.

The goal is to render a flatlist that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to add light opacity to the image by adding a view with an overlay and I tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have achieved so far:

[image]

This is the item in the flatlist:

```
    // console.log("item", item.latest_image.media[0].url);
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
    }
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          this.props.navigation.push(Screens.Photos, {
            team: item,
            id: this.props.navigation.getParam("team").id
          })
        }
      >
        <ImageBackground
          style={styles.backgroundImage}
          imageStyle={{ borderRadius: theme.borders_MediumRadius.borderRadius, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,.6)' }}
          source={{ uri: item.latest_image.media[0].url }}
        >
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

This is the flatlist:

```
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
          scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
          onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
        >
          <FlatList
            data={formatData(this.state.data, numColumns)}
            style={styles.container}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            numColumns={numColumns}
            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
          />
          <FollowUs />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

and these are the style props:

```
  container: {
    margin: 7.5,
    backgroundColor: "black"
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    height: hp("25"),
    backgroundColor: "black",
    margin: 7.5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  itemInvisible: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  itemText: {
    fontFamily: "RobotoCondensed-Bold",
    fontSize: RF(4),
    color: "black"
  },
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    margin: 7.5,
    height: hp("25"), // approximate a square
    borderRadius: theme.borders_MediumRadius.borderRadius
  }
});
```

If anybody could help me it would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your images seem to be broken.

Comment: @Maurice I have attached the links for the images alongside them, I'm not sure why they are not showing.

Comment: You could set a backgroundColor of white on your `TouchableOpacity`, then add some `opacity` to `ImageBackground`.

Comment: where did you import `hp` from line `height: hp("25"),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding a view around the text and giving it these props:

```
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",
              borderRadius: theme.borders_MediumRadius.borderRadius
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can achieve this

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            position: 'relative'
          }}>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{ uri: 'https://placehold.it/200x200' }}
            style={{
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              opacity: 0.6,
              position: 'absolute',
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's an example Snack - https://snack.expo.io/@hannigan/lonely-bubblegum

You should also set the `activeOpacity` on the `TouchableOpacity` to be the same value as what you will set on the `ImageBackground` (0.6)

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get the effect of a white opacity (that is one of the methods I tried before) but whenever I add opacity and active opacity it gives me a dim color. I want it to be white not dark like in the first picture in the post.